# Error Message: error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'setSize'

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm using an OpenCV4 Python textbook as a guideline. I have a set of images that I am using to train a machine learning algorithm to detect whether an LED is green, red or off. My steps are:

1. Use `glob` to `cv.imread` images from a file.
2. Optional image manipulation
3. Create labels
4. Use `KNN` or `SVM` (or some supervised learning algorithms)

I have everything except the ML algorithm working.  Why aren't I able to get this algorithm to work no matter what I try?

I'll paste a simplified version of my code.

Tried converting responses and samples to `np.float32`, switched from `KNN` to `SVM`, converted my images to single channel, reshaped `numpy` array, converted samples to `UMat`.

As far as I know:

I know the samples should be `np.float32` & `UMat`. 
The length of samples should be the same as the length of the responses.

I am using Ubuntu on Linux, and PyCharm as my DE.  Some sample training images here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AQ2fmCdtpTiSQZNLiKLKXNm1VwvRUrUI?usp=sharing

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import glob

def unpack(paths):
    files = []
    for path in paths:
        for file in glob.glob(path + '/*.jpg'):
            files.append(file)
    return files

def grab(file_paths):
    grabbed_imgs = []
    for fl in file_paths:
        grabbed_imgs.append(cv.imread(str(fl)))
    return grabbed_imgs

def get(grabbed_imgs, position):
    # pulls coordinates of LED, left out for simplicity. 
    # let xpt = (300, 350), ypt = (250, 300)
    xpt, ypt = locate_squares() 
    xpt = np.squeeze(xpt)
    ypt = ypt[position]
    ypt = np.squeeze(ypt)
    # set all values that aren't the LED location to black
    masked = []
    if len(grabbed_imgs) != 0:
        for im in grabbed_imgs:
        masked = np.zeros_like(im)
        xpt = [int(x) for x in xpt]
        ypt = [int(y) for y in ypt]
        for x in range(xpt[0], xpt[1]):
            for y in range(ypt[0], ypt[1]):
                for d in range(2):
                    masked[y][x][d] = im[y][x][d]
    return masked


g3 = ['/home/me/myFolderPath']
r3 = ['/home/me/otherFolderPath']

g3 = unpack(g3)
r3 = unpack(r3)


g3_images = grab(g3)
r3_images = grab(r3)

# g3 green r3 red.  For simplicity, I am leaving the off state out
g3 = np.squeeze(get(g3_images, position=3))
r3 = np.squeeze(get(r3_images, position=3))
samples3 = np.concatenate((g3, r3), 0)

# labels:  1 stands for green 2 stands for red
a = [1] * len(g3)
b = [2] * len(r3)
responses = a + b

print(len(samples3), len(responses), responses) # is as expected
>>> 75 75 [1,1,1,1,1...,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,...]

# SVM Machine Learning
gamma = 0.50625
C = 12.5
model = cv.ml.SVM_create()
model.setGamma(gamma)
model.setC(C)
model.setKernel(cv.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
model.setType(cv.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
model.setTermCriteria((cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6))

model.train(np.float32(samples3), cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE,     np.float32(responses))

# I also tried the KNN ML algorithm
knn = cv.ml.KNearest_create()
knn.train(samples3, cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, responses)
```

I get the error msg:

```
model.train(np.float32(samples3), cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE,         np.float32(responses))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0)     /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:235: error: (-215:Assertion     failed) s >= 0 in function 'setSize'
```

Comment: I think deploying a ML stack is a bit of overkill for this task at this point of time. You can simply use color segmentation, or mean color of the LED to get the color. Can you attach some sample images?

Comment: Here are a few photos.  I'm just looking at the 4th LED for now, just trying to determine the state of the one LED.  Later I want to determine the states of all the LEDs.  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LfRNqc1o0uP677Gj8tCq5fKI5V1zuK2F?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making sure the samples and responses were Numpy arrays.

```
def grab(file_paths):
    grabbed_imgs = []
    i = 0
    '''
    locate_squares() gets x and y coords for LED square 
    ex: x=[300,350] y=[200,250]
    '''
    x, y = locate_squares() 
    for fl in file_paths:
        '''
        this for loop helped fixed things for me
        '''
        pic = cv.imread(fl)
        # instead of function get()
        pic_crop = pic[y[0]:y[1], x[0]:x[1]]
        pic_flat = pic_crop.flatten() 
        pic32 = np.float32(pic_flat)

        grabbed_imgs.append(pic32)
    grabbed_imgs = np.squeeze(grabbed_imgs)
    return grabbed_imgs

g3 = ['/home/me/myFolderPath']
r3 = ['/home/me/otherFolderPath']

g3 = unpack(g3)
r3 = unpack(r3)

g3_images = grab(g3)
r3_images = grab(r3)

g3 = np.squeeze(get(g3_images, position=3))
r3 = np.squeeze(get(r3_images, position=3))
samples3 = np.concatenate((g3, r3), 0)

# labels:  1 stands for green 2 stands for red
a = [1] * len(g3)
b = [2] * len(r3)
responses = a + b

'''
switching to np arrays helped fixed things for me
'''
responses = np.array(responses)
samples3 = np.concatenate((g3, r3), 0)
# or could use np.vstack

knn = cv.ml.KNearest_create()
knn.train(samples3, cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, responses)
```